# alert value on graph hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is the fiddle for pie chart.

**[Pie Chart JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/)**

On hovering the slice, it displays slive value.

Can I alert the slive value onhover?

Actually my purpose is displaying another PIE chart for that slice on hover or click event of slice.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that.

in tooltip you have `formatter` this will allow you to have a javascript method to do your own stuff when a point is hovered on the chart.

```
formatter: function(){
    //your stuff here
}
```

Here is a working example for you : http://jsfiddle.net/XZvuL/

hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: you mean to show another chart when a slice of the pie chart is hovered??

Comment: I got is working, but still need to get value of slice http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Lx3SJ/.

Comment: yeah you can always have method that renders the new chart and call it from the event, either from tooltip formatter or mouseover event, updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Lx3SJ/2/

Comment: thanks dude, but I could not understand what cchanges you made. looks similar to my previous fiddle

Comment: i just put the code that created a new chart into a method and called it from tooltip with the value as argument, that value is plotted in the new pie chart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56998/discussion-between-user3449212-and-strikers).

Comment: your fiddle does not take the current value of slice in new graph, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function (event) {
                            var point = this;

                            alert(this.percentage)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2qGn2/)

Click Event

```
point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            var point = this;

                            alert(this.percentage)
                        }
                    }
        }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2qGn2/1/)

Comment: can I display graph for slice on click/hover?